# How to tell if SSH'd into machine?

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to tell if a terminal is SSH'd into a machine ? some kind of command to do this for me and execute something if I am SSHd?

Comment: If you're doing this for security, note that it's usually possible to hide the fact you came from ssh. e.g. `(env -i PATH="$PATH" /bin/bash some-script </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &)` - env -i to remove any environmental hints, subshell to make sure it re-parents to init ASAP instead of the shell under ssh, and redirections so that it can't be associated with the TTY. There are probably other tracks that can be covered too.

Comment: @Gnouc This is about an interactive shell, the one you link about a script/setting file. It is slightly different.

Answer (score 21):

You can check if the `$SSH_CLIENT` and the `$SSH_TTY` variables are set:

```
(through SSH) $ [[ -z $SSH_TTY ]]; echo $?
1
(local) $  [[ -z $SSH_TTY ]]; echo $?
0
```

The `$SSH_CLIENT` variable contains the IP you're connecting from, along with the remote and the local port:

```
(through SSH) $ echo $SSH_CLIENT
15.3.25.189 54188 22
```

Answer (score 6):

Try pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> then pressing <kbd>~?</kbd>.

If you're using an OpenSSH client you should receive a list of supported escape sequences which perform miscellaneous functions.

```
$ ~?
Supported escape sequences:
 ~.   - terminate connection (and any multiplexed sessions)
 ~B   - send a BREAK to the remote system
 ~C   - open a command line
 ~R   - request rekey
 ~V/v - decrease/increase verbosity (LogLevel)
 ~^Z  - suspend ssh
 ~#   - list forwarded connections
 ~&   - background ssh (when waiting for connections to terminate)
 ~?   - this message
 ~~   - send the escape character by typing it twice
(Note that escapes are only recognized immediately after newline.)
```

This will validate the connected state on the *local* machine as opposed to checking environment variables which are set on the remote machine and, thus, subject to remote configuration.

Comment: careful, on some OpenSSH clients, this terminates the ssh connection!

Comment: ~ by itself does not do anything for me. The two-letter sequences as in http://lonesysadmin.net/2011/11/08/ssh-escape-sequences-aka-kill-dead-ssh-sessions/ work.

Comment: Good catch. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I'd rather use `$?`. This answer is in a way complementary to the others currently present since this detects the connected state on the *local* machine while checking environment variables is a test run on the *remote* machine (and subject to remote configuration).

Comment: Great point. I've integrated this into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are the `$SSH_CLIENT` and `$SSH_CONNECTION` variables, but if you use a program like `screen`, these variables will remain set though they are obsolete. If this matters, you may want to use [my `escreen` and `sh.screen` utilities](https://www.vinc17.net/mutt/).